# Creating /tf (position) from IMU, 2D/3D SLAM (LiDAR+IMU+Octomap) (no need for high accuracy))

Tags: localization, octomap, rplidar, ros-kinetic, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Iam trying to build a simple SLAM system consisted of:

- RPLiDAR A2 M8
- Razor IMU 9DOF M0

**used packages:**

- octomap_mapping,
- razor_imu_9dof    (razor-pub.launch)
- rplidar_ros    (rplidar.launch)

**own packages**

- mctr-132_ros (sends transform of
  world 0,0,0 and transform of laser
  which has location 0,0,0 and
  orientation is quaternion from imu)
- mctr-132_laser (only converting
  LaserScan to PointCloud)

**System: Ubuntu 16.04, ROS Kinetic**

Iam in the phase that I put those points into map and I can visualize it in Rviz, but I only take IMU rotation into account. The position is being published into the /tf topic as 0, 0, 0. I can therefore build map of the surrounding environment. But I'd like to move my device around. So I need a proper /tf with position transform.
I was thinking about robot_pose_ekf, but it needs odometry and I have no idea how to create fake odometry from 9dof imu.

**Q1: Is it possible to create fake odometry from IMU and if so how?**

Many thanks

ps.: I would upload also a photo but 5 points are required...

ps.: I tried google cartographer, hector_localization, rf2o_laser_odometry but I failed to build/run them...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319016/creating-/tf-(position)-from-imu,-2d/3d-slam-(lidar+imu+octomap)-(no-need-for-high-accuracy))/) by [cergina](https://answers.ros.org/users/40551/cergina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am sorry I am really late to this thread but heres how I would do it, I would also love to hear how you ended up building your SLAM system.

2. Use a visual odometry software like a laser_scan_matcher (http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) or ICP odometry from rtabmap or hector_mapping (http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping) to emulate wheel_odometry data from the RPLiDAR
3. Fuse the visual odometry with IMU yaw and acceleration using the robot_localization package (This will give you a reliable odometry data source odom->base_link)
4. Use LiDAR data to build map and publish loop closures using rtabmap/ cartographer to correct the odometry drift (map ->odom)

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [indraneel](https://answers.ros.org/users/35902/indraneel/) with karma: 61 on 2019-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0